# Get Class context from prototype.object

Tags: javascript

Here's an example. I want to get the Animal context inside animal.skills.kick(). How i can implement this?

```js
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.run = function() {
  console.log('..running')
}

Animal.prototype.skills = {
  kick: function() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

var animal = new Animal('rabbit');

animal.skills.kick()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do sounds like a very bad design to me, but one way to do it would be to move the skills declaration in the constructor:

```
function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name;

    var that = this;
    this.skills = {
        kick: function() {
            console.log(that);
        }
    };
}

Animal.prototype.run = function() {
    console.log('..running');
}

var animal = new Animal('rabbit');

animal.skills.kick();
```

Comment: Can you explain why it's bad design? Is it bad to extend prototype in Class.prototype.obj = {} way? I can't got it.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add an argument to kicks and pass in your animal, or you would have to create kicks as a member function of animal and not skills.

'this' refers to the object that invoked the method. In your code the skills object invoked the method. Skills is a part of animals (an attribute) but skills is not an animal.

The following would work:

```
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.run = function() {
  console.log('..running')
}

Animal.prototype.skills = {
  kick: function(animal) {
    console.log(animal)
  }
}

var animal = new Animal('rabbit');

animal.skills.kick(animal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this.skills.className = this.name; to the class

```
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.skills.className = this.name;
}

Animal.prototype.run = function() {
  console.log('..running');
};
Animal.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name;
};
Animal.prototype.skills = {
  dummy: 6,
  kick: function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.className);
  }
};

var animal = new Animal('rabbit');

animal.skills.kick();
```